# Understanding Linker Error: DSO missing from command line

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ldd

So lately, I have been trying to better understand how the symbol resolution with shared libraries works. I have created 2 shared objects (`libfoo` and `libbar`) and 1 executable (`test`). Consider following set of programs:

`foo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo()
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

`bar.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void foo(void);
void bar()
{
    puts(__func__);
    foo();
}
```

`test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void);
int main()
{
    puts(__func__);
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

`libbar` depends on `libfoo`, and `test` depends on both `libfoo` and `libbar`:

```
gcc -c -Wall -fPIC foo.c bar.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar.o -L. -lfoo
```

Now while building test, I deliberately don't provide the direct dependency on `libfoo`:

```
cheshar@editsb:~/2-test $ gcc -o test test.o -L. -lbar -Wl,-rpath-link=.
    /usr/bin/ld: test.o: undefined reference to symbol 'foo'
    ./libfoo.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

cheshar@editsb:~/2-test $ ldd libbar.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe27bf7000)
    libfoo.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7d203e0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7d209ac000)
```

As we can see that `test` needs symbol *foo* and depends on `libbar` which in turn depends on `libfoo` and has the required symbol. So my question is why can't the linker resolve the symbol? Shouldn't it be able to scan all the dependencies and link to make the executable?

Answer (score 1):

In order to link your executable you will need to add `-lfoo` in your command line.
The libraries passed by command line and the ones "passed" by rpath will not have the same treatments. The ones passed by command lines will be treated by `open_input_bfds` while the onse "passed" by rpath will be treated by `ldemul_after_open` which is  `gldelf_x86_64_after_open` for x86.
The error you are seeing is coming from `bfd_elf_link_add_symbols` and it is a choice of gnu. in this function you have this code:

```
      /* A symbol from a library loaded via DT_NEEDED of some
     other library is referenced by a regular object.
     Add a DT_NEEDED entry for it.  Issue an error if
     --no-add-needed is used and the reference was not
     a weak one.  */
      if (old_bfd != NULL
      && (elf_dyn_lib_class (abfd) & DYN_NO_NEEDED) != 0)
    {
      _bfd_error_handler
        /* xgettext:c-format */
        (_("%B: undefined reference to symbol '%s'"),
         old_bfd, name);
      bfd_set_error (bfd_error_missing_dso);
      goto error_free_vers;
    }
```

And from the change log:

- elflink.c (elf_link_add_object_symbols): Check DYN_AS_NEEDED,
  DYN_DT_NEEDED and DYN_NO_NEEDED bits to see if a DT_NEEDED
  entry is needed. Issue an error if a DT_NEEDED entry is needed
  for a file marked DYN_NO_NEEDED.

the fact is that libfoo.so will be marked as needed by libbar.so and not by test.o . There is a dt_needed structure that will be created in `gldelf_x86_64_search_needed`.

```
lang_process
-> ldemul_after_open ()=gldelf_x86_64_after_open
-->gldelf_x86_64_search_needed (dt_needed created)
--->gldelf_x86_64_try_needed
---->bfd_elf_link_add_symbols
----->elf_link_add_object_symbols ( the error )
```

Also if you don't want to add `-lm`, you can add the weak attribute to foo in test.c `extern void __attribute__((weak)) foo(void);` and the linker will not complain anymore. As mentioned earlier , it a gnu choice ( and i did not find any explanation in the commentary, documentation or change log). But only in my opinion it is a protection to avoid picking the wrong symbol.

Comment: "_the fact is that libfoo.so will be marked as needed by libbar.so and not by test.o_" so what you are saying is that only libraries provided with `-L<path> -l<libname>` will be marked as DT_NEEDED in the SO/relocatable object files? Even though `libbar` has `libfoo` marked as NEEDED in dynamic section, the same is not present in `bar.o`. Secondly, I understand what you are saying is that "this is how it is done", but not why it is done this way.

Comment: the libraries passed with '-l -L' are handled with open_input_bfd functions which occur early before gldelf_x86_64_search_needed. the needed ones will be marked as DT_NEEDED. libfoo in this example will be passed later with a structure `dt_needed` which will contain two fields : needed=libfoo.so and by=libbar. However the reason why foo cant be picked from libfoo.so unless it is a weak is not mentioned in the code or the change logs. May be you can ask directly in the mailing list.but in my opinion it's to make sure to take the right symbol (that's why the weak is accepted).

Comment: Just encountered the same problem, when I really forgot adding the -l flag (in my case -lXrandr). But what puzzles me: where does it know that lib in the first place ?
Is it already linked by some other lib in the dependency chain ?
Is this error just to protect me from subtle makefile bug ? (IOW: require all linking to be explicit, in order to prevent bad surprises in case some implicit linking goes away by some lib upgrade ?)